# How to use Neo4J via Spring Roo 1.2.x?

Tags: neo4j, spring-roo, spring-data-neo4j

**How to use Neo4J via Spring Roo 1.2.x?**

Books & online documentation seem to suggest that Neo4j is a search addon with Spring Roo 1.2.4.  Although I can manually add the spring-data-neo4j dependency, I would really like to leverage the Roo capabilities.

```
Spring Roo  1.2.4.RELEASE [rev 75337cf]

roo> addon search graph

0 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the dev site of [spring-roo-addon-graph](https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-graph/). It looks like the addon has been updaded for the Roo-1.2.2. on Oct 23, 2012, but has disappeared somehow from roobot repo.

The author of the book "Roo in Action" by Ken Rimple, has left an [issue on Oct 4, 2012](https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-graph/issues/detail?id=5):

> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> > 1. Try to do a addon search graph
>
> **What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
>
> > The add-on could be made available.
>
> **What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
>
> > Roo 1.2.2, OS X
>
> **Please provide any additional information below.**
>
> > The Roo development team lost the add-on repository database from the roobot process. Your
> >     graph add-on is no longer registered with them. Please re-submit by
> >     sending an email to s2-roobot@vmware.com with the add-on OBR xml file
> >     in the subject line.